# Nested IEnumerable/Arrays, how to access a deeply nested property

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

So I have an IEnumerable object that contains a queue(list), each item contains 3 properties. One of those properties ("States") contains another array... and this array contains the property "Messages". Fairly confusing, that's why I took a photo of the local in debugging. [image: I had to edit sensible data out, sorry guys]
Had to edit sensible data out.

I only have this IEnumerable object to work with. How do I reach the property "message"?

I already tried some Lambda expressions... Like

```
var _message = _criticalData.Select(item1 => item1.States.Select(item2 =>item2.Messages).ToArray()).ToArray()
```

Then I can create a new array/list of strings and foreach each _message into it.

Atleast I think it works (can't test it at home). But it would also be really really slow. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It would have been much much more helpful if you showed your classes instead of an image.

Comment: I know, sadly I can't access the code remotely. And I didn't want to spam this questions with 4 pictures of classes

Comment: How does both `item1` and `item2` (which is the State itself) both have a States property ?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake there, edited it out *blush*

Comment: You mean like `_criticalData.SelectMany(x => x.States.SelectMany(y => y.Messages))`?

Comment: Holy, I didn't even know that there was selectmany method.... thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to flatten out multiple lists, so use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
string[] output = _criticalData.SelectMany(outer => 
                            outer.States.SelectMany(inner => inner.Messages))
                            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Holy, I didn't even know that there was selectmany method.... thanks. :)